# Coloring the axis tick text by multiple colors

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap, axis-labels

I'm trying to plot a `heatmap` using `R`'s `plotly` package, where I'd like to have specific colors to specific labels of the y-axis tick text.

Here's an example dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- reshape2::melt(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10,dimnames = list(paste0("G",1:10),paste0("S",1:10))))
```

And here's what I'm trying:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
plot_ly(z=c(df$value),x=df$Var2,y=df$Var1,colors=grDevices::colorRamp(c("darkblue","gray","darkred")),type="heatmap",colorbar=list(title="Scaled Value",len=0.4)) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title=list(color=c(rep("darkred",5),rep("darkblue",5)))))
```

It's not working since I'm getting:
[image]

Changing:    `yaxis=list(title=list(color=c(rep("darkred",5),rep("darkblue",5))))`

To:  `yaxis=list(title=list(color=list(c(rep("darkred",5),rep("darkblue",5)))))`

Or: `yaxis=list(title=list(tickcolor=c(rep("darkred",5),rep("darkblue",5))))`

Or: `yaxis=list(title=list(tickcolor=list(c(rep("darkred",5),rep("darkblue",5)))))`

Doesn't seem to help.

Any idea?

Comment: For a single color used tickfont: layout(yaxis=list(tickfont=list(color = "darkred"))) --- but can't do a tickfont array for two different colors on same axis. Looks like may be a feature request: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3204

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A similar question with a different setup has been asked and answered for Python here: [Setting a different font color for specific x axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549944/setting-a-different-font-color-for-specific-x-axis-ticks). Below is my best attempt with your setup for R.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# data
set.seed(1)
df <- reshape2::melt(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10,dimnames = list(paste0("G",1:10),paste0("S",1:10))))

# plotly setup
p1 <- plot_ly(z=c(df$value),x=df$Var2,y=df$Var1,colors=grDevices::colorRamp(c("darkblue","gray","darkred")),
              type="heatmap",colorbar=list(title="Scaled Value",len=0.4)) 

p2 <- p1 %>% add_trace(xaxis='x2', showscale=FALSE)

p3 <- p2  %>% layout(xaxis=list(range=list(0,9),
                                tickvals=list(0,1,2,3,4),
                                tickfont=list(color='red')),
                     xaxis2=list(range=list(0,9), overlaying='x',
                                 ticktext = list('s9', 's10'),
                                 tickvals=list(5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                                 tickfont=list(color='blue')))
# plot it
p3
```