# Format specific tick labels in plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I’m plotting some districts indicators in a heatmap and I wanted to highlight the selected districts by coloring them red in the y axis (each tick in the yaxis is a district name). I know in matplotlib you can loop through each tick, but here I’m not finding anything. Is there any way I can do this?

The relevant piece of my code is this one:

```
colors = ['black']*len(ranking)
idx = (ranking[ranking.district.isin(selected_districts)]).index.values
for i in idx:
    colors[i] = 'red'
fig.update_yaxes(color=colors)
```

As color doesn’t accept an array, my approach isn’t working. Is there any way with a lower level API to achieve this? I know this isn't a reproducible example, but my question is quite generic and data independent, but if needed I can add one.

Edit:

Working example:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
y = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
x = [1, 2]
z = [[3,4],[5,7],[8,9]]
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

Let's say I want to make the `2b` tick red. How could I do that?

Comment: Do you mind to share a sample of your data?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: This doesn't seems to be possible at the moment see [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/possible-to-customize-individual-colors-of-x-axis-tick-labels/17847/2?u=baobob) unless you play with annotations or a fake yaxes as in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550240/4819376)

Comment: Thanks @rpanai, I was fearing I'd have to do a double ax to achieve what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using `tickmode = 'array'` and `ticktext` and with some inserted html, see [here](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array) for more info.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
y = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
x = [1, 2]
z = [[3,4],[5,7],[8,9]]
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z)

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = y,
        ticktext = ["<span style='color:blue';>1a</span>",
                    "<span style='color:red';>2b</span>",
                    "<span style='color:green';>3c</span>"]
    )
)
fig.show()
```

For your situation, I think you would build a list for your `ticktext`, something like:

```
flag = [False, True, False]

tt=[]
for i, why in enumerate(y):
    if flag[i]==True:
        tt.append("<span style='color:red';>" + why + " </span>")
    else:
        tt.append("<span style='color:black';>" + why + " </span>")

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode='array', tickvals=y, ticktext=tt
    )
)

fig.show()
```

...where `flag` is defining where you want red text (similar to your `idx`), although there are lots of ways to do this part.

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Do you think it's possible to change ff.create_annotated_heatmap for go.Heatmap? I heard they are planning to drop figure_factory

Comment: yes, you can drop in `fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z))` directly... but you'll loose the annotations.

Comment: My bad I meant go.Heatmap and annotations.

Comment: Wow, that's nice to know! Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

First check @jayveesea's answer, this will solve your problem. Then, in case you might be interested, you could use `go.Heatmap` with exactly the same `fig.update_layout`

```py
y = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
x = [1, 2]
z = [[3,4],[5,7],[8,9]]
fig = go.Figure(go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z))

ticktext = [i if i!="2b" else f"<span style='color:red';>{i}</span>" for i in y ]
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array',
        tickvals=y,
        ticktext=ticktext
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: this is a more elegant generation of `ticktext` too