# Plotly: How to highlight certain xticks?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

```
class parser(object):
    """docstring for parser"""
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.encodeCSV = pd.read_csv(path, ',')
        self.metrics = {
                         "train_rmse" : "RMSE_Tr",
                         "validation_rmse" : "RMSE_V",
                         "train_90_quantile" : "90QT_Tr",
                         "validation_90_quantile" : "90QT_V"
                       }

    def generate_img(self):
        fig = go.Figure({
                         'layout' : {'title': {'text': 'Combination Model'},
                                     'xaxis': {'title': {'text': 'Models'}},
                                     'yaxis': {'title': {'text': 'KPI Values'}}}
                            
                        })

        for metric in self.metrics:
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=self.encodeCSV['names'],
                                     y=self.encodeCSV[metric],
                                     mode='lines+markers',
                                     name=self.metrics[metric]))
        return fig
```

I have generated a figure to analyze models' performance by plotly.

Here is a sample
[image]

Now I have to highlight a model with best result and one straightforward way is just change the color of the xtick of the model (change the color of the circled xtick as following)
[image]

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549944/setting-a-different-font-color-for-specific-x-axis-ticks) to be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are easier ways than adding more axes as suggested in the comments. Plotly recognizes html formatting, so you can easily format only one of the values that goes into the x argument in `go.Scatter()` like `'<em>'+x+'</em>'` to get this:

#### Plot 1:

[image]

Admittedly, the `C` does not stand out *that* much, so what I like to do instead of adding separate axes, is adding separate *traces* to make certain points on the figure stand out. Here I've combined an extra trace with som html formatting as well:

#### Plot 2:

[image]

What I like best about this approach is that it adds some extra value through increasing interactivity when you can opt to show or hide the highlighted points by clicking on the names in the legend. I hope you'll find this useful. Don't hesitate to let me know if something is unclear.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': list('ABCDE'),
                   'y': [2,4,1,3,5]})

#df['y_min'] = np.where(df['y']==df['y'].min(), df['y'], np.nan)
# series with formatted x values using a list comprehension
# (further improvements are welcomed!)
#df['x_txt'] = ['<i>'+x+'</i>' if np.isnan(df['y_min'].iloc[i]) else '<b>'+x+'</b>' for i, x in enumerate(df['x'])]

# Edited -->
# Create list containing x-labels.
ymin = df['y'].argmin()
xlabels = [f"<i>{x}</i>" for x in df['x']]
xlabels[ymin] = xlabels[ymin].replace('i', 'b')

# Create array of y values.
y = np.full(df['y'].size, np.nan)
y[ymin] = df['y'].min()
# <--

# plotly
fig = go.Figure()

# add highlighted point first to appear in the back
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = xlabels, y = y,        # Edited
                             mode = 'markers',
                             marker = dict(color='red', size = 12),
                             name = 'best'))

# add the main values to the figure
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = xlabels, y = df['y'],   # Edited
                             mode = 'lines',
                             marker =dict(color='blue'),
                             name = 'other values'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Nice approach, and simply illustrated.

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks! Appreciated!

Comment: @S3DEV That `for i, x in enumerate(df['x']):` mess could probably be replaced by something more elegant. So feel free to throw in a little edit there if you should feel so inclined =)

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Will have a think on it.  The first thing that comes to mind is something along the lines of `np.argmin()` to get the index to be edited in the xaxis labels list.

Comment: @S3DEV Changed the For Loop to this: `df['x_txt'] = ['<i>'+x+'</i>' if np.isnan(df['y_min'].iloc[i]) else '<b>'+x+'</b>' for i, x in enumerate(df['x'])]`. Shorter? Yes. More readable? Hardly...

Comment: There you go mate. Popped a couple of ideas into the code for you, marked by the three `# Edited` comments.  Granted ... it's a couple more lines, but (personally) the logic is more concise.  Do with it as you please ... pop it on the bin if you like!  :-)

Comment: @S3DEV `np.full()`? Never heard of it. I like it!