# How to color or bold a specific axis label in Plotly?

Tags: python, r, plotly

Let’s say I have the following plot

```
import plotly.express as px
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()
```

[image]
I want to be able to bold, or highlight, or make ‘stand out’ a specific label, such as ‘1980’ in this case.
Is there a way to specify this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems there's no direct and easy way to set this... but there's some workaround, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550240

Comment: Why is this tagged `r` ?

Comment: Plotly is both a python and r package, with very similar syntax throughout