# Modifying individual tick labels in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Suppose I have some code such as,

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

p <- plot_ly(data, x=~Animals, y=~SF_Zoo, type='bar', name='SF Zoo') %>%
     add_trace(y=~LA_Zoo, name='LA Zoo') %>%
     layout(yaxis=list(title='Count'), barmode='stack')
```

I'm trying to figure out how I color the three x-axis labels (giraffes, monkeys, orangutans) different colors, I've been trying to do this by using something like,

`xaxis=list(tickfont=list(color=c('red', 'yellow', 'blue')))`

inside the `layout` function, but it doesn't work.

How can I modify tick labels individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time being this isn't as straight forward as `xaxis=list(tickfont=list(color=c('red', 'yellow', 'blue')))` since the color of the tick labels are associated with the properties of the axis and not the individual ticks. You *can* assign different colors to different parts of the visible axis, but you'll have to **add extra axes**. This has been done in detail here: [Coloring the axis tick text by multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486547/coloring-the-axis-tick-text-by-multiple-colors/58643916#58643916)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a trick to use HTML syntax for this use case.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)  

plot_ly(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      tickmode = "array",
      tickvals = 1:3,
      ticktext = c(
        "<span style='color:red'>A</span>",
        "<span style='color:yellow'>B</span>",
        "<span style='color:blue'>C</span>"
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: This is a great solution because it is quite easy to implement and is highly readable.