# Plotly: How to set different colors for x-axis labels using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, plotly

I'd like to set different colors for date labels on the x axis so that each month has a different color. 
Like the example below. I don't know if such a topic already exists, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

```
library(plotly)
today <- Sys.Date()
tm <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)
x <- today + tm
y <- rnorm(length(x))
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  %>%
  layout(
      xaxis = list(
      type = 'date',
      tickformat = "%d %b %Y"
    ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The topic already [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061655/modifying-individual-tick-labels-in-r-plotly/59065608#59065608). What you're looking to do is possible, but a bit complicated since the colors of the tick labels are associated with the axis and not the ticks themselves. The best current approach is to [add extra axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486547/coloring-the-axis-tick-text-by-multiple-colors/58643916#58643916).